# Disabling hinting and code fixes for eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse and i notice that everytime that i highlight a line of code, eclipse freezes for a bit if i try to go to another line quickly.Below is a line that i have highlighted.

[image]

Its clear that eclipse is doing something in the background once i highlight a class or an entire line as shown. I would like to know if there was a way to disable whatever eclipse is doing when i highlight a class and also i want to disable the hinting as shown in the yellow background box.

How can i configure the two things in eclipse?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong in understanding what you're asking, you want to disable displaying the `Javadoc` for the corresponding Java class or method. You can conveniently do this by following the steps provided below:

On Eclipse, click on the `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` tab (on the left) -> `Editor` -> `Hovers` -> Uncheck the checkbox for `Javadoc`

This will disable eclipse from searching for any available `Javadoc` for the class / method that you point on (in eclipse - Java code)

Hope this helps!